# About the yield of scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, yield

I have generated many URLs in advance. I need to decide to whether to continue to crawl the next URL according to the `DateTime` of the content of URL. However I can't implement this kind of check because of the `yield`.

Pseudocode:

```
for url in urls:
    if not Auth(url.content.datetime):
        break
```

I have tried setting the timestamp of a global post in order to determine whether the time meets the criteria for the next URL request. But it seems to be limited by `yield`, which is not executed, and which is a generator.

code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
domain = "guba.eastmoney.com"


def make_urls(code: list) -> list:
    return [f"http://{domain}/list,{x}.html" for x in code]


url_list = make_urls(['000001'])


class EsCommentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'es_comment'
    allowed_domains = ['guba.eastmoney.com']
    start_urls = url_list

    def headers(self):
        return {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"}

    def start_requests(self):
        for x in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(x, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        count = response.xpath('//*[@class="sumpage"]/text()').extract_first()
        count = 20
        urls = [response.url]
        for x in range(1, count):
            urls.append(f"{response.url.replace('.html', f'_{str(x)}.html')}")
        for url in urls:
            # I need to get the datetime  in page_parse function  and  decide whether to continue 
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.page_parse, headers=self.headers())

    def page_parse(self, response):
        lis = response.xpath(
            "//div[contains(@class,'articleh normal_post')]").extract()
        for x in lis:
            block = etree.HTML(x)

            datetime = block.xpath("//span[@class='l5 a5']/text()")[0]
```

Comment: Please post more code. Your question is currently very unclear. What does "limited by `yield`" mean?

Comment: I wanted to crawl some of the blogs, and I got all the urls up front. Depending on the date of the specific content of the blog (known only after the crawl), you need to decide whether to crawl the next blog. Scrapy's yield mechanism doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I forgot to label scrapy ~

Comment: You've not really cleared it up to me. Until you post your code I can't help you. What you are trying to do is very common, so I'd be surprised if it doesn't fit with the model

Comment: Sorry, give me some time and  I write a demo for you.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/p/645qMMw28b this is the code

Comment: Can you edit your question rather than giving a link?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Do you need to stop the spider based on the response content? Yield different URLs depending on the response content?

Comment: I have solved this question by using requests together.